# DB2 seconds to time conversion issue

Tags: date, type-conversion, db2, seconds

Problem : some row has dirty data which cant be converted as date, So query failing

- in db2 date is stored in seconds
- while transferring data to sql server we are converting to datetime

  Query to convert as datetime

`select TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01', '00:00:00') +(Startdate/1000) SECONDS from tablename`

- some row has dirty data which cant be converted as date

Need query to find error data

Desired query :

`select TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01', '00:00:00') +(Startdate/1000) SECONDS 
from tablename 
where iserror (TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01', '00:00:00') +(Startdate/1000) SECONDS) = 1`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: some row has dirty data which cant be converted as date, so query failing

Comment: @vignesh Please, don't make us guess. If your query fails - what's the exact error code and message you get? What does it mean "dirty data"? What's the data type of the `Startdate` column? Is it `[var]char` and does it contain some data not castable to `int`?

Comment: sorry. Error message returned : A datetime arithmetic operation or a datetime scalar function has a result that is not within the valid range of dates

Answer (score 0):

You may create a scalar function to suppress such an error:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

create or replace function ms2ts(p_milliseconds bigint)
returns timestamp
contains sql
deterministic 
no external action
begin
  declare continue handler for sqlexception begin end;
  return TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01', '00:00:00') +(p_milliseconds/1000) SECONDS;
end@

-- Usage:
select *
from 
(
  select ms2ts(startdate) ts, Startdate
  from table(values 
    power(bigint(2), 45)
  , power(bigint(2), 60)
  ) tablename (Startdate)
)
-- where ts is null
@

TS                                 STARTDATE             
--------------------- ----------------------
3084-12-12 12:41:28.0         35184372088832        
<null>                   1152921504606846976
```